# Scenario diagram vs sequence diagram

Tags: uml

What's the difference between sequence diagrams and scenario diagrams in UML?

Answer (score 2):

"Scenarios" per your link aren't diagrams, they're narrative text.  They're also called "Use Case Narratives" among other terms.  They are approximately equivalent to other behaviour specifications (sequence diagrams, activity diagrams).

There are generally three differences:

1. Format.  Scenarios are textual, sequence/activity diagrams are, well, diagrams
2. Content.  Textual narrative is often  used to describe the sequence of interactions between the user and the "system" in Use Case descriptions.  Hence there are usually only two participants (User & System).  In contrast, sequence diagrams are primarily used to show how behaviour is distributed among objects.  Consequently there will usually be more than two participants.
3. Formality. Narratives are often used earlier in the cycle to get an idea of what's needed.  Consequently they're often less formal than Sequence diagrams - which typically show inter-object messages ("method calls").

For examples of tools that do this, take a look at [websequencediagrams.com](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/).  Or search for "free UML tools".

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean **System** Sequence Diagram (SSD) and Sequence Diagram.

The purpose of SSD is to illustrate a particular use-case scenario in a visual format where the system appears as a black box.

Sequence Diagram, on the other hand, shows how system objects interact over time for achieving a particular scenario of a use-case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no diagram type called scenario. Maybe you are thinking of collaboration?

Sequence and collaboration diagrams are actually the same: the Sequence depicts the chronology while the Collaboration depicts the interactions between the collaborators. Together (a tool that was around a decade ago) used to let you literally just change the setting and see the diagram in the other mode.

<sub>I use OmniGraffle (Mac). It's great for class diagrams. Has support for Sequence diagrams but not Collaboration.</sub>

Comment: scenarios diagram do exist, http://www.primaryview.org/UML/Scenarios.html anyways, would you recommend any tool just for collaboration diagrams on windows?

Comment: I didn't find them in any of the lists, wikipedia, etc. Collaboration was renamed in 2.0 to communication. http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm